# Alternative to pthread_mutex_lock in Swift?

Tags: swift, concurrency, singleton

I'm trying to save singletons into a dictionary and locking the dictionary with a mutex like this:

```
return cached[key] as? T ?? {
    let object = SomeObject()
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)
    cached[key] = object
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)
    return object
}()
```

Is there a Swifty or better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of mutex lock you can use equivalent NSLock like this,

```
let lock = NSLock()
lock.lock()
cached[key] = object
lock.unlock()
```

but the most Swifty way of doing is using GCD DispatchQueue,

```
private let serialiserQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue.name")
serialiserQueue.sync {
    cached[key] = object
}
```

These are other options also available like NSRecursiveLock, OperationQueue(similar to DispatchQueue) you can take a look at them and decide.